# There is no registered service of type error, when I have a registered type

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I followed a tutorial for saving data in a Blazor App. I have an `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BlazorApp1.Shared.Models;
using System;

namespace BlazorApp1.Shared.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<SurveyModel> surveyModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I have registered it as a service in `startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I have injected it into my Survey.razor page with `@inject BlazorApp1.Shared.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context`

I am getting the error:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property '_context' on type 'BlazorApp1.Client.Pages.Survey'. There is no registered service of type 'BlazorApp1.Shared.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
```

Comment: Hi Heather, What version of blazor is this? Your DbContext seems to be in a shared library?

Comment: It's the most recent version, I created the web assembly app two days ago. It is in a shared library, yes.

Comment: You cannot inject a DbContext in WASM

Comment: Well shoot. That sucks. Thank you for your help, though!